# What is _data in object received from firestore?

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore in my react native app.
In some case I calling firestore to get all docs from specific collection and for some reason the array of data received in wrong format.

```
{"_data": {"clinicAddress": "1", "clinicName": "Macab", "description": "Nice doctor I think", "docs": [], "doctorName": "Caaw", "timestamp": 1652290939, "title": "Check my ears"}, "_exists": true, "_metadata": {"_metadata": [false, false]}, "_ref": {"_documentPath": {"_parts": [Array]}, "_firestore": {"_app": [FirebaseApp], "_config": [Object], "_customUrlOrRegion": undefined, "_nativeModule": [Object], "_referencePath": [FirestorePath], "_settings": [Object], "_transactionHandler": [FirestoreTransactionHandler]}}}
```

How can I get only the objects inside data?

Here is my interface:

```
export interface Appointment {
  clinicAddress: string;
  clinicName: string;
  description: string;
  docs: any[];
  doctorName: string;
  timestamp: number;
  title: string;
}
```

And this is the function to fetch the data:

```
export const fetchAppointments = (): Promise<any> =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const data = await firestore().collection('users').doc(auth().currentUser?.uid).collection('appointments').get();
      resolve(data.docs);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      reject(e);
    }
  });
```

Comment: This object is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) and you'll find all the available properties and methods at this link.

Answer (score 1):

Ok , I found this way to fix this , but not sure that this is the right way.

```
export const fetchAppointments = (): Promise<any> =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const data = await firestore().collection('users').doc(auth().currentUser?.uid).collection('appointments').get();
      const cleanData = data.docs.map(data => data._data);

      resolve(cleanData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      reject(e);
    }
  });
```